# mediaelement.js: listen to event triggered from mep-feature-ads

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

i'm trying to use mediaelement.js for playing videos on our website. we want to present ad-videos before the mainvideo. to track, which ad was viewed how many times, i want to send an ajax-call to my custom php-script, when the ad is finished.

My problem is, that i can't add a listener to the correct item where the `mep-feature-ads` function `adsPrerollEnded` triggers the callback:

```
adsPrerollEnded: function() {
    console.log('adsPrerollEnded');

    var t = this;

    t.container.trigger('mejsprerollended');

    t.adRestoreMainMedia();
},
```

At the time my code looks like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
        features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','volume','fullscreen','ads'],
        adsPrerollMediaUrl: '../media/echo-hereweare.mp4',
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            // add event listener
            mediaElement.addEventListener('mejsprerollended', function(e) {
                alert('ad is over, do ajax now');
            }, false);          

            // call the play method
            mediaElement.play();
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

but the alert is never fired, besides all other functions work fine (the ad is played before the mainvideo and no controls are available during the ad, after the ad the mainvideo starts).

I think the `t.container` from the ads-feature isn't the same as `mediaElement` in the success-function.

on some researching with `console.log()` i figured out, that `t.container` is the `<div id="mep_0"` element. `mediaElement` is the `<video>` tag burried in `class=mejs-inner` and `class=mejs-mediaelement`

So how do i register a listener on `mejsprerollended`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

mejs is using the jquery `.trigger` function, so i have to use the jquery eventlistener-register-function `.on`:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video',{
    features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','volume','fullscreen','ads'],
    adsPrerollMediaUrl: '../media/echo-hereweare.mp4',
});
player.container.on('mejsprerollended',function(e){
    alert('ad is over!');
});
```